# Редактор адреса компании Yandex Map

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-places-api

Добрый день! Есть справочник по компаниям. У компаний есть координаты в Яндекс картах (записаны в Mysql).

Необходимо дать возможность в личном кабинете просмотреть на карте текущее положение организации на карте Яндекс и дать если что возможность поправить его. Видел такие редакторы Карта + Строка поиска адреса (юзер вносит адрес компании, если он неточно отображается на карте, вручную переносит балун). Есть такая карта со строкой поиска в готовом виде?

Я бы скормил ей текущее положение балуна с центрирвоанием на нем карты и если юзер захочет, то введет адрес новый компании, тем самым поправит координаты на новые (или перенесет балун на новое место мышью). Как итог - новые координаты в переменной которую потом записываем в MySql.

Какое нибудь частично готовое решение есть? Не хочется собирать по кускам карту с нуля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готового решения нет, но минимальное решение будет такое:

1. Создаете карту и ставите в центр карты метку по координатам организации. Для метки задайте `draggable: true`, чтобы разрешить менять её положение на карте.
2. Слушаете событие завершения драга на метке и по нему записываете новые координаты в базу.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  var bizCoords = [55.76, 37.64], //координаты из БД
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
      center: bizCoords,
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),

    // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
    myBizPoint = new ymaps.Placemark(bizCoords, {
      iconContent: 'ООО Рога и Копыта'
    }, {
      preset: 'islands#redStretchyIcon',
      draggable: true
    });

  myBizPoint.events.add('dragend', function(e) {
    // новые координаты, которые нужно записать в БД
    console.log(myBizPoint.geometry.getCoordinates());

  })

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myBizPoint)

}
```

```css
</style><script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script><style>html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Перетащите метку, чтобы указать правильное местоположение организации</p> 
<div id="map"></div>
```